# How does RocketReach fetches email ids?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what is the underlying technology or method employed by RocketReach.co to fetch email ids, for example from linkedin?
I tried few searched but could not find anything.

Comment: It is likely that agreements have been made with companies like Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn to share their email addresses.

Comment: So RocketReach subscribes to it? And if that is the case how can anyone else subscribe to it? instead of going through RocketReach.